# How to export a global variable from a C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, variables, dll, unity-game-engine

The problem is I'm trying to access a global variable declared in a C++ DLL from a C# program. Even though I set the variable to 15 in a repeatedly called function (Subtract in this case), each time I invoke the getter (Divide in this case), the return value is zero.
So here's my code. Header file:

```
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public: 
        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Add(double a, double b); 

        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Subtract(double a, double b); 

        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Multiply(double a, double b); 

        static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double Divide(double a, double b); 
    };
}
```

C++ code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double signID; //this is my variable

__declspec(dllexport) double __cdecl MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b){
   //.. some code
   signID = 15; //this function is the setter
}

__declspec(dllexport) double __cdecl MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
{
    return signID; //this function is the getter, it return zero when called from C#
}
```

In my C# code I used the method found here: http://www.quantcode.com/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=95
I keep getting a zero return value from the getter function, why, and how can I fix this?

Edit: C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


static class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}

public class SignDetector : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Lets make our calls from the Plugin
    [DllImport("CVDetectorDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = @"?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")]

    private static extern double add(double a, double b);
    [DllImport("CVDetectorDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = @"?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")]

    private static extern double subtract(double a, double b);
    [DllImport("CVDetectorDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = @"?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")]

    private static extern double multiply(double a, double b);
    [DllImport("CVDetectorDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = @"?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")]

    private static extern double divide(double a, double b);

    double myvariable;

    void Start(){
        subtract(0, 0); //here we invoke the setter

        IntPtr mydll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("CVDetectorDLL.dll");

        //get a pointer to unmanaged heap address
        IntPtr addrUnmanagedHeap = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(mydll, "signID");

        if (addrUnmanagedHeap != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //convert and read memory from unmanaged pointer 
            myvariable = Marshal.ReadInt32(addrUnmanagedHeap);

        }
    }

    void Update(){

        Debug.Log("Found = " + myvariable); //prints zero
        Debug.Log("Found = " + divide(0,0));  //getter
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your C# code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like both my original code and the posted solution will indeed work - I seem to have misidentified the problem which was actually not in the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing (without seeing your c# code that the issue is in your calling convention. __cdecl is default for C++ as noted [MSDN __cdecl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx)

and it means that the calling function is responsible for the stack. In this case your .net program. c# defaults to the calling convention of __stdcall. This is very important for methods that take or return parameters as it determines how the stack will behave.

I have included code which should show you a way to make this work.

c++ Code Header

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { //Used to prevent name mangling on dll export
#endif //__cplusplus

double signID;

DLLEXPORT void __stdcall SetDoubleValue();
DLLEXPORT double __stdcall ReturnDoubleValue(double dummyone, double dummytwo);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif //__cplusplus
```

c++

```
void __stdcall SetDoubleValue()
{
    signID = 15;
}

double __stdcall ReturnDoubleValue(double dummyone, double dummytwo)
{
    return signID;
}
```

c# import code

```
[DllImport("DllExport.dll")]
public static extern void SetDoubleValue();

[DllImport("DllExport.dll")]
public static extern double ReturnDoubleValue(double dummyone, double dummytwo);
```

Note if you can't or don't want to change from __cdecl you can also change your c# definitions to

```
[DllImport("DllExport.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetDoubleValue();

[DllImport("DllExport.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double ReturnDoubleValue(double dummyone, double dummytwo);
```